# How to Connect Android Device with web serve using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-json

I have this asynctask.I need to connect device with web server.Need to send a JSON Arry and receive JSON array. Can i use httpUrlConnection ? or httpClient. Does httpClient support latest versions of Android?

```
  class background_thread extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {

        //connect with server side php script
        String UR = "127.0.0.1/abc/index.php";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(UR);
            try {

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                json_array=json_encode();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                writeStream(out);




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        return true;

    }
```

Comment: In 6.0(Marshmallow) HttpClient does not support.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use google's own volley library to make network calls and handle the response data in model classes. This is the most modular approach. Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) link for official documentation.